# Setting KivyMD app launch screen in Xcode 12.1

Tags: ios, xcode, kivy, kivymd, launchimage

I have developed a game with KivyMD for Android & iOS with Xcode 12.1. Everything works fine on Android. I have resized my app icon and launch image to various sizes that Xcode needs. In my Xcode project's General tab, I was able to set my app icon source to the `appiconset` folder that was generated for me when I resized my app icon and launch image. However, I am not sure how to set my app's launch image. With Xcode 12.1, it appears the button "Use Asset Catalog" has been removed and hence I am not able to set the LaunchImage folder.

My current iPhone run on iOS 14.1 and hence I had to upgrade Xcode accordingly.

Can someone help?